# How to add plugin new cordova /phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

can you please tell me how to add plugin in android /iphone using latest cordova 3.0 .Actually I worked on cordova 2.7 .That time I use java or objective c code to make plugin (like child browser and email composer).But some developer said now in build in cordova .So can you please tell me how to add plugin .Example Email composer /Childbrowse ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use InAppBrowser instead of Childbrowser. Check following link.1)https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/58 2)http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/implementing-inappbrowser-into-a-cordova-phonegap-project/

Comment: is we do same way add .h/.m file and using js file we call native class and recieve response

Comment: someone told me that you don't need to add plugin class there is inbuild come using some command

Comment: Yes...and InAppBrowser is inbuilt plugin simply have to call some method. are you try this way ?

Comment: I recentlly two day ago I have added push notification plugin for ios.

Comment: how  ? Added .h/.m file ? .what about email composer ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43175/discussion-between-user2648752-and-ved)

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean "InAppBrowser"?
You can add plugins like these via [CLI](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

In your project directory:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```